# How to use Apache Arrow IPC from multiple processes (possibly from different languages)?

Tags: python, ipc, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm not sure where to begin, so looking for some guidance.  I'm looking for a way to create some arrays/tables in one process, and have it accessible (read-only) from another.

So I create a `pyarrow.Table` like this:

```py
a1 = pa.array(list(range(3)))
a2 = pa.array(["foo", "bar", "baz"])

a1
# <pyarrow.lib.Int64Array object at 0x7fd7c4510100>
# [
#   0,
#   1,
#   2
# ]

a2
# <pyarrow.lib.StringArray object at 0x7fd7c5d6fa00>
# [
#   "foo",
#   "bar",
#   "baz"
# ]

tbl = pa.Table.from_arrays([a1, a2], names=["num", "name"])

tbl
# pyarrow.Table
# num: int64
# name: string
# ----
# num: [[0,1,2]]
# name: [["foo","bar","baz"]]
```

Now how do I read this from a different process?  I thought I would use [`multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html), but that didn't quite work:

```py
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='pa_test', create=True, size=tbl.nbytes)
with pa.ipc.new_stream(shm.buf, tbl.schema) as out:
    for batch in tbl.to_batches():
        out.write(batch)

# TypeError: Unable to read from object of type: <class 'memoryview'>
```

Do I need to wrap the `shm.buf` with something?

Even if I get this to work, it seems very fiddly.  How would I do this in a robust manner?  Do I need something like zmq?

I'm not clear how this is zero copy though.  When I write the record batches, isn't that serialisation?  What am I missing?

In my real use case, I also want to talk to Julia, but maybe that should be a separate question when I come to it.

PS: I have gone through the [docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ipc.html), it didn't clarify this part for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I need to wrap the shm.buf with something?

Yes, you can use `pa.py_buffer()` to wrap it:

```py
size = calculate_ipc_size(table)
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, name=name, size=size)

stream = pa.FixedSizeBufferWriter(pa.py_buffer(shm.buf))
with pa.RecordBatchStreamWriter(stream, table.schema) as writer:
   writer.write_table(table)
```

Also, for `size` you need to calculate the size of the IPC output, which may be a bit larger than `Table.nbytes`. The function you can use for that is:

```py
def calculate_ipc_size(table: pa.Table) -> int:
    sink = pa.MockOutputStream()
    with pa.ipc.new_stream(sink, table.schema) as writer:
        writer.write_table(table)
    return sink.size()
```

> How would I do this in a robust manner?

Not sure of this part yet. In my experience the original process needs to stay alive while the others are reusing the buffers, but there might be a way to get around that. This is likely connected to this bug in CPython: https://bugs.python.org/issue38119

> I'm not clear how this is zero copy though. When I write the record batches, isn't that serialisation? What am I missing?

You are correct that *writing* the Arrow data into an IPC buffer does involve copies. The zero-copy part is when other processes *read* the data from shared memory. The columns of the Arrow table will reference the relevant segments of the IPC buffer, rather than a copy.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! And for the link to the Python issue :) I'm wondering if using your implementation of `calculate_ipc_size` also serialises the data?  That would mean I end up serialising twice.  I intend to share a large-ish table, it might mean a noticeable delay.

Comment: You do serialize twice--sort of. But since `calculate_ipc_size` is writing to a `MockOutputStream` that first time is very fast. No bytes are actually written, it's just counting the bytes. On my machine I am able to write about 10 gigabytes per second into shared memory.

Comment: Ah cool! thanks a lot for the testing :) That's plenty fast for my use case :)